# How to build a multi-layer LSTM in Tensorflow for a video sequence?

Tags: video, tensorflow, lstm, multi-layer

I want to build a 3 layer LSTM in tensorflow for video analysis. I read some examples online, but still confusing. Could anyone help to write a concise code snippet to do a task as below:

Input: 5 consecutive video frames in 240X320 dimension

Output: 5 scalars

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please post the example or your effort? This will help us in better understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to prepare you frames for the sequence. You should have a vector like (Batch_size, sequence_length = 5, features = 240*320). Then create your 3 Stacked LSTM using:

```
layer1 = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(number_lstm_units)
layer2 = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(number_lstm_units)
layer3 = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(number_lstm_units)
```

Group the cells and pass it to a Multi RNN Cell:

```
cells = [layer1, layer2, layer3]
multirnn = rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
```

Then with your flattened vector of features you only have to pass each element though the LSTM

```
for feature in your_flattened_vector:
    lstm_output, state = cell(feature,state)
```

You will have an output of the same size as your input.

For additional info check the API [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell).

Hope it helped.